# USB camera not seen by some applications in 18.04

Tags: drivers, usb, video, webcam, camera

I have just installed 18.04 MATE.
I have two cameras available, one built-in and the other a usb eye-cam.
In 16.04, both were seen by cheese (Cheese->Preferences->Webcam).
In 18.04, cheese only registers the built-in one.
However, the other camera IS visible to guvcview and vlc.
I have tried playing with dconf Editor without effect.

dsmesg reports:

```
16.354843] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   16.374078] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device SCMOS02000KPB (053a:9230)
[   16.378130] uvcvideo 2-1:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
[   16.378133] uvcvideo 2-1:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 6 was not initialized!
[   16.378135] uvcvideo 2-1:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[   16.378231] input: SCMOS02000KPB: SCMOS02000KPB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/input/input20
[   16.380953] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device HD WebCam (04f2:b452)
[   16.392232] uvcvideo 2-7:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
[   16.392236] uvcvideo 2-7:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
[   16.392240] uvcvideo 2-7:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[   16.392358] input: HD WebCam: HD WebCam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-7/2-7:1.0/input/input21
[   16.393383] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   16.393385] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or is this just a bug?

Thanks

Comment: I am currently experiencing the same problems with cheese in Ubuntu 18.04

$ cheese 

cheese-application.vala:211: Error during camera setup: No device found

The webcam works correctly with vlc using v4l2:///dev/video0

The usb info for this webcam is

Bus 001 Device 008: ID 046d:08d9 Logitech, Inc. QuickCam IM/Connect

Comment: I have the same warnings at dmesg using integrated Dell XPS9360 webcam

Answer (score 0):

Issues at the dmesg report are harmless and doesn't affect Cheese. Here's the details about messages: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=111291#c9